# Passing value from aspx page to its user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to pass value from my aspx page to ascx (user control). So, I make a property in user control and initialize it at the page load of the page, when I debug it, I see that property gets assigned in the page load of aspx page but in the usercontrol it comes as null.

Pageaspx page :

```
        private string _id;
        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Id = "ASPX1";
            Pageascx g = new Pageascx();
            g.PageTitle = Id;
        }
```

Pageascx.ascx My usercontrol (THIS USER-CONTROL is used in my Pageaspx.aspx)

```
          private string _pageTitle;
          public string PageTitle {get; set;}
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          { 
            if (PageTitle == "ASCX1") // **Here, I get PageTitle = null**
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not initialize a new usercontrol as local variable in the `Page_Load` method of your page. Instead you should use `Page.LoadControl("UserControlName.ascx")` if you want to add it dynamically. Otherwise you can access it either directly if it is on top of the page or via `control.FindControl("UserControlID")` if it's sitting in a child control like a `GridViewRow`.

So if it is added declaratively(on the aspx code) this should work:

```
userControlID.PageTitle = Id;
```

But note that all variables or controls are disposed at the end of the pages lifecycle. You need a way to [persist them  across postbacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx), otherwise `PageTitle` is null on the next postback. You could use a control like `Label`, `TextBox`, `Hiddenfield` or the `ViewState`/ `Session`.